# How is Read the Air meant to be used?

Tags: spells, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

The *Secrets of Magic* spell [*read the air*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=981) reads in part

> You also gain a +1 status bonus on your next Diplomacy check to Make an Impression on those creatures present when you cast this spell, as long as the check occurs during the duration of the spell.

Said duration is one minute, which happens to also be the absolute minimum time required to Make an Impression.  Absent class feats that specifically change this rule, Casting a Spell is obvious to anyone who can see or hear the caster, and I've had a lot of trouble imagining how this spell could actually be used.

A conversation starts, a cleric decides that they would like to favorably impress someone they are talking to, they start chanting and gesturing and divine light fills the room, and then somehow people who were indifferent are going to let this obvious lunatic proceed directly to trying to impress them?

All the scenarios I can imagine involve subterfuge powered by [Conceal Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=640) or equivalent.  Am I misunderstanding something?  Should the spell be run as an exception to the usual rules?  What options am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Possibly non-intrusive components

The first paragraph of the cantrip seems to be describing what the somatic and verbal components of the spell *are*:

> You take a deep breath as you survey a social situation, showing courtesy to all around you as your intuition swiftly picks up clues about social contexts and unspoken assumptions of behavior. Your body language subconsciously changes to take advantage of this information and use it in your own interactions with those creatures.

Note that there is a "verbal" element ("the deep breath") and a somatic element ("body language changes", "showing courtesy to all around you").

Given this, and two reasonable assumptions:

1. It's clear the designers wanted this to be a *useful* cantrip - why would they have made it otherwise? [Conceal Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=640) is a Wizard feat, and Wizards can't cast this cantrip without multiclassing, so it's highly unlikely it was intended to work *only* with Conceal Spell.
2. In a high-magic fantasy world, it's probably not a social faux paus to cast magic around other people anyway. It's one thing if the magic targets someone (where they would feel the effects), but given this magic **targets only yourself**, it seems like it'd cause as much offense as casting [Purify Food and Drink](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=241) would.

It's okay to cast this spell in a social situation around other people. There's a RAW argument to be made that these components, while obviously noticeable, are nothing "disruptive" (see the quote from the cantrip), and RAI it seems clear that the goal of the spell is to be able to use it in social situations.

### NB: Glad-Hand

If you're worried about the duration being a problem (it shouldn't be with the ruling this answer argues for), you could always check out [Glad-Hand](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=787). It allows you to try to make an immediate, quick impression.

Comment: Was also thinking of Glad-Hand, but the line about only working on "those creatures present when you cast this spell" makes me think that wouldn't work to avoid this problem.

Comment: I thought about this too, if the first paragraph maybe is *intending* to describe how you cast the spell, so it would not be perceptible; but in other spells I checked, the description was the effect of the spell, and chapter 7 says "A horizontal line follows saving throws and duration, and the effects of the spell are described after this line", so I think this cannot descibe the components part during casting.

Comment: @brandon yeah, it's not a very useful combo, but for some reason if you're worried about Making an Impression taking more than a minute (it is *at least* 1 minute), then it makes Read the Air actually usable.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin - that's chapter 7 of the CRB? I'll hunt through when I get back to my physical books - it is possible that the formatting in Secrets of Magic conveys some meaning that gets lost when transferred to AoN, however unlikely.

Comment: @ESCE Well the issue is that Glad-Hand activates immediately when you meet someone, rather than after you cast a spell next to them. So you couldn't meet someone -> cast spell with them present -> Glad-Hand

Comment: @brandon interesting - I think that depends on how the "rather than" is interpreted. And maybe even "meet" . Might be worth a separate question, albeit the answer might be "stop being so pedantic ESCE" .

Comment: The spell references creatures "present" when it's cast and refers to a "social situation", not necessarily a conversation. You could cast this outside of conversation then go to the person throwing the party and (if the GM is sane regarding the 1m duration) get the bonus. Glad-Hand is potentially a great way to capitalize on this benefit more than once, if you can successfully enter and exit a conversation within a minute (may or may not be appropriate depending on the situation)

Comment: Also, I only ever use Glad-Hand with Assurance so for a second I was like 'the bonus doesn't apply to Glad-Hand' but I caught myself haha

Comment: Yes, it appears to be on [page 306](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=303) if you want to check your book.

Comment: People seeing you start to cast would have to trust you enough not to counterspell and attack.  I'm assuming the default in Pathfinder is like 5e that people don't know what kind of spell you're casting until it goes off, so guards at a gate for example might have a cautious policy of reacting with hostility to anyone casting after being asked to justify why they should be let in.  Because they don't know it's not Fireball, or Charm Person on both of them.  At a formal event, if people know you're a fellow invited guest, that could be a lot different and play out as you describe.

Comment: @PeterCordes Recognizing a cantrip like this is really easily available to anyone with even basic magical training in PF2e (see [Recognize Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=834), a level 1 skill feat), whereas Counterspelling is much much more difficult. I don't think the 5e assumption can carry over here.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin yeah, the formatting on Nethys does match both the formatting of Read the Air in SoM and the CRB "how to read a spell" section, so we're good there. I'll see if I can find another example like this - however, should this even be a unique example, I believe my arguments still hold.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it's the consensus answer and because I think that the other answers leave the spell pretty much useless.  It's not obviously correct, but it is supportable.

Answer (score 5):

### The spell is difficult to use if you cannot conceal it

I don't think you misunderstand anything. As you correctly observe, casting spells without license by others in a social environment is going to be at least awkward, if not seen as a hostile act. Likewise the rules are explicit about spellcasting being observable. The text for Verbal components says:

> You must speak them in a strong voice, so it’s hard to conceal that you’re Casting a Spell.

And the [Conceal Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=640) feat likewise states that "*material, somatic, and verbal components are usually noticeable*".

You have some other side benefits in that you Recall Knowledge using Society as part of casting the spell, but that is something you also could do without the spell, and casting a spell in polite society for that purpose would be just as problematic as casting it to influence someone, as your counterparts do not know what you are up to.

This spell only does make sense in a social situation. To deploy it usefully, you will pretty much need to combine it with some means that allow you to cast a spell without observers noticing, such as the Conceal Spell feat.

---

PS. I first thought, like in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/203948/75095), that maybe the introduction of the description following after the horizontal line is depicting the casting of the spell, so it would be innocuous

> You take a deep breath as you survey a social situation, showing courtesy to all around you (...)

but the Reading Spells section in [Chapter 7, Spellcasting (p. 306)](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=303) explains:

> A horizontal line follows saving throws and duration, and the effects of the spell are described after this line.

so unfortunately, I think this description must pertain to the effect of the spell, and not to the verbal and somatic components for casting it.

Answer (score 3):

### Where Spellcasting is Allowed

Many folks might react poorly to some cleric or bard chanting and clearly casting a spell in their presence socially, but with the fairly magical default Pathfinder 2e setting it makes sense that even trepidatious observers might let it slide with no bolt of lightning or other overt effect on another creature.

Describing the spell's effects as "reading the air" may just strengthen a commoner's belief that casters are a bit odd, or make perfect sense to the gathered conclave of other spellcasters.

Even in social situations where some spellcasting might be allowed however, it's likely imposing to continue casting as it becomes disruptive to the larger scene. Chanting in a [strong voice](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=284) isn't exactly conducive to casual conversation, though bards can [substitute](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=281) the Verbal component with instrument playing.

For other cases, as you've mentioned there's the option for [concealing](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=640) the spellcasting if you're a witch or wizard. This is available for any character with 14 Intelligence via [multiclass archetype](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx), costing 2 class feats.

Comment: Is there any published (in rulebooks or AP's) that actually reference NPC's reactions to spellcasting? Citing something would help this answer a lot, I think.